# if my screen refresh rate is 60 hertz What exactly does that mean?

Tags: windows, display, external-display, refresh-rate

if my screen refresh rate is 60 hertz What exactly does that mean?

Also, how do i increase/decrease this screen refresh rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the image on the screen is refreshed 60 times a second. It can be changed in the advanced display properties to any refresh rate the display supports.

Comment: Using the word refresh to define what a 60 Hz refresh rate is is a tautology.  Better to use other words like redraw.  The screen is redrawn 60 times a second.